# Unable to change maximum execution time asp.net, Sql Query taking too long for execution

Tags: asp.net, sql, execution-time

I have an SQL Query, that takes about 8-10 minutes for execution, i want to change the server execution time so that the result of the query be displayed on the webpage.

The webpage stops responding after 30 Sec

I tried the following

In the  File

```
httpRuntime executionTimeout="200" maxRequestLength="25600"
```

In the connection string

```
add name="AgeingConnectionString" connectionString="DataSource=DTB00B51237\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ageing;Integrated Security=True;ConnectionTimeout=200" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Changing the "debug" to "false"

```
compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Still the page stops after 30 Secs

Comment: I checked, no such issue

Comment: httpRuntime maxRequestLength units is KB ,i guess your execution data size is more than 25MB ? And if you use GridView to show data result , you can try disable ViewState. To set  GridView EnableViewState="false"

Answer (score 1):

Solved

attach this with the every sql command being executed

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;
```

where `900` is the maximum time(in sec) that the query will wait for the response